# grammar / meaning “They left the house at 6.00 a.m. and would reach Edinburgh some 12 hours later.”

Tags: meaning, grammar

The explanations of my grammar book is as follows.

1. “They left the house at 6.00 a.m. and would reach Edinburgh some 12 hours later.” (=they reached Edinburgh)
2. He was sure that the medical tests would show that he was healthy. (=we don’t know whether he was healthy or not)

I think I understand sentence 2 (from the context of “he was sure”) but how do we know the fact (=they reached Edinburgh) in sentence 1?
And how about saying “and reached Edinburgh some 12 hours later.”? (because we know that the tense is “the future seen from the past” from the time expression of “12 hours later”)
And is it possible for us to know whether something did happen or not in following sentences? Then how or why can we know?

1. “I was going to do the washing, but we would run out of washing powder.”
2. The exam was so easy that most people would have finished after 30 minutes.
3. So in my excitement I arrived early. I would putt some; maybe do some
   chipping;

Likewise, how about saying (1)“we ran out of ---“, (2)”finished--- .
I think that “would” in sentence (3) refers to “prediction” and we don’t know about the happening yet until the speaker tell us about the result.
Am I wrong? Then may I know why?

Comment: Sentence 1 is relating an historical "fact".  It is as true as the source is reliable.  Sentence 2 is simply giving an opinion.

Comment: Yes, in theory *They left the house at 6.00 a.m. and would reach Edinburgh some 12 hours later* is at best unnatural. Prolly the only scenario in which we might expect it would be if they failed to reach Edinburgh and the missing-persons squad was thinking aloud about what might have happened.

Otherwise yes, it should be *… and reached Edinburgh some 12 hours later*

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Another scenario is the relating of history. Just as it would be natural to read: "Grant's army left Louisiana in 1963 and would reach Savannah, Georgia in late 1964."